# C# now has biginteger, but what about support for arbitrary precision floating point numbers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Now that biginteger (System.Numerics.BigInteger) support has been added in C# 4.0, it would be nice if arbitrary precision floating point/fixed point was also possible. Are there any good (preferably free) third party libraries that offer efficient arbitrary precision floating/fixed point capabilities?

Comment: So you wanna a "bigdecimal" right? Please see this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421612/very-very-large-c-floating-point-numbers

Comment: That would be nice, but that's Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arbitrary precision floating- and fixed-point numbers can easily be coded as ratios of BigIntegers.  I don't know of any off-the-shelf libraries for them but then I don't know much about C#.